# remove items from one object those are matched with other object items

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6

i have an object structure is like this as below

```
"designProjects": [
  {
    "projectNumber": "number1",
    "name": "test1"
  },
  {
    "projectNumber": "number2",
    "name": "test2"
  },
  {
    "projectNumber": "number3",
    "name": "test3"
  },
]
```

i have another object that is having structure like this as below

```
"allProjects": [
  {
    "project": {
      "name": "test1",
      "number": "number1"
    },
    "employee": {
      "displayName": "name1"
    },
    "projectRoleName": "Editor"
  },
  {
    "project": {
      "name": "test2",
      "number": "number2"
    },
    "employee": {
      "displayName": "name2"
    },
    "projectRoleName": "Editor"
  },
]
```

I am kind of looking the results like as below

```
"designProjects": [
  {
    "projectNumber": "number3",
    "name": "test3"
  },
]
```

here the results is  `designProjects` is only having one because the project number and name matched with `project` array of `allprojects` object. Is there way we can achieve this results in `react js`.
Any suggestions or ideas would be very grateful to me, Many thanks in advance

Comment: So, do you want to get project number 3 (difference) or projects number 1 and 2 (intersection)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would just combine `.filter` with `.some`, something like:

```js
let d = {
  "designProjects": [
    {
      "projectNumber": "number1",
      "name": "test1"
    },
    {
      "projectNumber": "number2",
      "name": "test2"
    },
    {
      "projectNumber": "number3",
      "name": "test3"
    },
  ]
}

let a = {
  "allProjects": [
    {
      "project": {
        "name": "test1",
        "number": "number1"
      },
      "employee": {
        "displayName": "name1"
      },
      "projectRoleName": "Editor"
    },
    {
      "project": {
        "name": "test2",
        "number": "number2"
      },
      "employee": {
        "displayName": "name2"
      },
      "projectRoleName": "Editor"
    },
  ]
};

console.log(
    d.designProjects.filter((designProject) => {
        return !a.allProjects.some((project) => designProject.projectNumber === project.project.number && designProject.name === project.project.name);
     })
 );
```

Comment: sorry i cannot be able to combine with those two , is it possible with out combining those..

Comment: you can't combine what two? `.filter` and `.some`?

Comment: like this `let Obj = {}` i cannot be able to combine ..

Comment: you don't have to combine them, just replace `obj.designProjects` with whatever object it really is, and `obj.allProjects` with whatever object it really is.  It doesn't matter whether they are on the same object or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

`filter` is used to return a new filtered array based on a condition

`some` will be the condition and return as soon as it finds a match

```js
const designProjects = [{
    "projectNumber": "number1",
    "name": "test1"
  },
  {
    "projectNumber": "number2",
    "name": "test2"
  },
  {
    "projectNumber": "number3",
    "name": "test3"
  },
];

const allProjects = [{
    "project": {
      "name": "test1",
      "number": "number1"
    },
    "employee": {
      "displayName": "name1"
    },
    "projectRoleName": "Editor"
  },
  {
    "project": {
      "name": "test2",
      "number": "number2"
    },
    "employee": {
      "displayName": "name2"
    },
    "projectRoleName": "Editor"
  },
]

const cleaned = designProjects.filter((x) => {
  return !allProjects.some(y => y.project.number === x.projectNumber);
});

console.info(cleaned);
```